# I cannot send keys because element not interactable in selenium web automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In the code below I cannot send the username or password in the corresponding fields. I receive every time an "Element not interactable" exception. Could anyone please tell me how to solve the problem?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import sys


def main():
    path = r'path\to\chromedriver.exe'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.get("https://banking.dkb.de/login")

    try:
        # Accept cookies #
        frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='privacy-iframe']")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Refuse all cookies']")
        button.click()

        # In order to be able to find the elements after accepting cookies
        driver.get("https://banking.dkb.de/login")

        #Logging in
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")
        element.send_keys("123456789")
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")
        element.send_keys("abcdefg")
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-11z3xzm-3 bFajen']/button")
        element.click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Element not found')
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit(0)

    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timeout exception')
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit(0)

    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        print('Element not interactable')
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit(0)


main()
```

[Screenshot of the Website HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KkoB.png)

I tried setting an implicit and explicit wait and setting the value through a javascript clicking the field but still didn't work. Could anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def main():
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get("https://banking.dkb.de/login")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Switch to the iframe and click on the button to refuse all cookies
    iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe#privacy-iframe')))
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn.refuse-all').click()

    driver.get("https://banking.dkb.de/login")

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="sui-input-username"]'))).click()
    username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#username')
    actions.move_to_element(username).send_keys('123456789').perform()

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="sui-input-password"]'))).click()
    password = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#password')
    actions.move_to_element(password).send_keys('abcdefg').perform()

    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)

main()
```

output:

[image]

**Few notes**:

- The website may display a cookie consent popup within an iframe. Therefore, switch to the respective iframe and click on the button to refuse all cookies.

  ```py
  iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe#privacy-iframe')))
  driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn.refuse-all').click()
  ```
- Initialize ActionChains to perform actions like mouse movements and keystrokes

  ```
  actions = ActionChains(driver)
  ```
- Log in with provided credentials, Find the username input field, click on it, and enter the username.

  ```py
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="sui-input-username"]'))).click()
  username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#username')
  actions.move_to_element(username).send_keys('123456789').perform()
  ```
- Find the password input field, click on it, and enter the password.

  ```py
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="sui-input-password"]'))).click()
  password = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#password')
  actions.move_to_element(password).send_keys('abcdefg').perform()
  ```
- Press the Enter key to submit the login form.

  ```py
  password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped a lot! I was missing this important line:     wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="sui-input-username"]'))).click()
Now it worked! I still have a question: Why do you recommend to use the ActionChains class? I could send the keystrokes just with username.send_keys("123456789") instead of actions.move_to_element(username).send_keys('123456789').perform()

Comment: And another question: why is it necessary in this case to click in the div[data-testid="sui-input-username"] before sending the keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Actions should help you in this case

```js
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("[data-testid=sui-input-username]")).click();
#Logging in
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")
actions.send_keys('login', element).perform()
```

I did similar approach for your site in Java and it worked for me.
Also I think you don't need to refresh page after cookies modal is closed.
You just need to wait for modal to be not visible and switch to default context after that.

Check modal for invisbility

```html
refuseButtonSelector = "//button[@aria-label='Refuse all cookies']"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, refuseButtonSelector)
button.click()

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, refuseButtonSelector)))
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, it worked! How exactly can I avoid to refresh the page after refusing cookies? Could you suggest the code?

Comment: @SeverOmpty posted code for you to not to refresh the page (from button.click() and below)

Comment: Very nice, it worked! Thank you very much!!